# How can I access localisable strings for standard iOS system terms (E.g. Favorites, More...)?

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I don't know if my approach to this is fundamentally wrong, but I'm struggling to get my head around a (seemingly trivial?!) localisation issue.

I want to display the title of a 'System' UITabBarItem (More, Favorites, Featured, etc...) in a navigation bar. But where do I get the string from? The strings file of the MainWindow.nib doesn't contain the string (I didn't expect it to) and reading the title of the TabBarItem returns nil, which is what stumped me.

I've been told, there's no way to achieve it and I'll just have to add my own localised string for the terms in question. But I simply don't (want to) believe that!! That's maybe easy enough in some languages, but looking up, say, "More" in already presents me with more than one possible word in some languages. I'm not happy about simply sending these words for translation either, because it still depends on the translator knowing exactly which term Apple uses. So am I missing something simple here? What do other people do?

Obviously, setting the system language on my test device and simply looking to see what titles the Tab Items have is another 'obvious' possibility. But I really have a problem with half baked workarounds like that. That'll work for most languages, but I'm really gonna have fun when it comes to Russian or Japanese.

I'm convinced there must be a more reliable way to do this. Surely there must be a .strings file somewhere in the SDK that has these strings defined?

Thanks in advance...
Rich

Comment: I have also been looking for this and had no luck.  However, the UIBarButtonItem does support this. for example the UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd button type will show up in the correct language running on the iOS Device.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question, and the solution is to dig the strings out of AppKit.   This may also work for getting your iOS strings.      http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/202866-getting-localized-system-strings.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple and unfortunate answer is that aside from a very few standard elements (e.g. a Back button), you need to localize all strings yourself. Yes, UIKit has its own Localization.strings file but obviously that's outside of your app sandbox so you don't have access to it.

I filed a bug with Apple years ago about providing OS-level localization for common button titles, tab item labels, etc. That bug is still open but obviously they haven't done it yet (sorry, I don't have the radar # handy).